# UIViewController transparent background colour

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm trying to achieve the following behavioural attached in the image and I did it using vies with custom classes, the question is that how can I achieve this using view controllers, [image]

the behavioural works as follow: when tapped and swipe left the previous screen should start appear but without pop from navStack, just slide to show and when user leave his finger will return to initial state which same as above image, I did it by adding a UIGestureRecognizer on this white slide edge start change the x position for the upper view but, both upper and previous are views not UIViewColtrollers, the question is how to implement this using UIView controllers or make the background colour  of the upper view controller transition colour.

have any idea about this or do sth like this before to help ?

Comment: 2 possible solutions you could look up is custom view controller transitions OR child view controllers

Comment: I did it by make the view controller background colour transparent and it's worked